# SQL % difference based on baseline

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a date column, 8 columns of group and location data, and then a total area sum. For any given set of those 8 columns, I want to calculate what % the current value is based on whatever the first month was, which might vary based on rows.  So for example I might have:

| Date | C1 | C2 | C3 | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | foo | bar | baz | 9876 |
| 2023-02-01 | foo | bar | baz | 5432 |
| 2023-01-01 | foo | bar | blip | 1234 |
| 2023-03-01 | foo | bar | baz | 1011 |

I'd then want this output (without the reason column of course):

| Date | C1 | C2 | C3 | % | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | foo | bar | baz | 100% | Initial value, so 100% |
| 2023-02-01 | foo | bar | baz | 55% | 5432 / 9876 = 55% |
| 2023-01-01 | foo | bar | blip | 100% | Initial value, so 100% |
| 2023-03-01 | foo | bar | baz | 10% | 1011 / 9876 = 10% |

So I'm always dividing the current row's area by the initial area for the row with the same C1, C2 and C3 values.

To make it more complicated, each unique C1/C2/C3 might have separate "first" dates.  It won't always be 2023-01-01 like the below example.

Comment: Have you had a look at `FIRST_VALUE`?